# Sass::SyntaxError in Devise::Registrations#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, sass

I for the first time use Devise. When generated the user model and I tried to register the first user according to the link - http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up. There is a mistake:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/44uMT.png

routes.rb:

```
Diary::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root 'static_pages#welcome', as: 'welcome'
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: The error message indicates the problem exists in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:58`. Can you post the file contents for that line?

Comment: In that that I have a problem of only 18 lines there

Comment: Can you post all the contents then?

Comment: Can you please tell how did you resolve this error?